# Selecting and Deselecting Master Checkbox on the basis of child checkboxes using JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I am using JQuery and I have below HTML with checkboxes in it. I have got one master checkbox called `chkSelectAll` and the child checkboxes inside the DIV.

```
 <div class="selectallitems">
                    <div class="selectall">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" CssClass="selectall-txt" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divCheckAll">
                        <div class="selectall">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItemLists" CssClass="selectall-txt-1" runat="server" />
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="selectall">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkComponentLinks" CssClass="selectall-txt-1" runat="server" />
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="selectall">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkResourceKeyData" CssClass="selectall-txt-1" runat="server" /></div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now I want whenever user selects `chkSelectAll` then it should select all other checkboxes and whenever user deselect any of them it should deselect the `chkSelectAll` as well as if all the three checkboxes are again selected then `chkSelectAll` will be selected also and if all the three are not selected then master checkbox `chkSelectAll` will also be deselected.

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an optimized and more compact version. The others should work fine, but they are running selectors all the time unnecessarily. Here all the selectors are saved in the beginning.

```
var $selectAll=$('#chkSelectAll'),
    $checks=$('#divCheckAll :checkbox');

$selectAll.change(function () {
    $checks.attr('checked', this.checked);
});

$checks.change(function () {
    $selectAll.attr('checked', $checks.not(':checked').length==0);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DBgzH/)

Answer (score 1):

For my app I used something like this:

```
// This would select / deselect all.
$('#chkSelectAll').change(function() {
    $('.selectall-txt-1').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

For the master select checkbox you could use something like this:

```
$('.selectall-txt-1').change(function() {        
    var checkedAll = $('.selectall-txt-1 :checked').length == $('.selectall-txt-1').length;
    $('#chkSelectAll').attr('checked', checkedAll);            
});
```

Comment: thanks @enoyhsm, but this will only select and deselect according to the master checkbox, however I want if user deselect any of the child check box, then the master checkbox should also be deselected and same if user again selects all the three checkboxes then the master checkbox will automatically will be selected again.

Comment: Updated the answer. Have to recheck if all syntax is OK. But the idea is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
// Master checkbox
$(".selectall input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    $("#divCheckAll input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", this.checked);
});

// Child checkboxes
$("#divCheckAll input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var isAllChecked = $(".selectall input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 3;
    $(".selectall input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", isAllChecked);
});
```

Comment: what you are trying to do here as this code is not working for me. Master Checkbox code is OK what about child checkboxes

Comment: I check if we got 3 checked child checckboxes. If true, we check the masetr chcekbox, if false, we uncheck the master checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot like Oleg G.'s answer, except the length isn't hardcoded, I use removeAttr to uncheck, and I use jQuery's nifty `:checkbox` selector:

```
$.masterCheck = function(master, boxes) {
  master.change(function() {
    if (master.is(':checked'))
      boxes.attr('checked', 'checked')
    else
      boxes.removeAttr('checked')
  });

  boxes.change(function() {
    if (boxes.is(':not(:checked)'))
      master.removeAttr('checked')
    else
      master.attr('checked', 'checked')
  });
};

$.masterCheck($('.selectall:checkbox'), $('#divCheckAll:checkbox'));
```